# How to obtain the relationship between a plane and a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, rouches-theorem

I want to know if my reasoning can hold in general, of if there are caveats or if it's simply a load of nonsenses.

Say I have to determine the position of a line with respect to a plane. Say I have the equation of a plane in cartesian form, for example:

$$\sigma: x + y - z + 1 = 0$$

and a parametric equation of a line, like

$$\begin{cases}
x = 2t\\
y = t+1 \\
z = -t
\end{cases}
$$

Now the question: instead of using matrices representation and Rouché-Capelli's Theorem, could I just say that

- If by substituting the parametric equations into the equation of a plane I get $0 = 0$ or $2 = 2$ and so on, then the line belongs to the plane (always true system/identity);
- If by substituting the parametric equations into the equation of a plane I get something like $1 = 0$ or $3 = -1$ and so on, then the line and the plane are parallel (impossible system);
- If by substituting the parametric equations into the equation of a plane I get $3t = 0$ or $t = -5$ and so on, then the line and the plane are incident (the line passes through the plane, unique solution system).

So, can I, or is this method a failure?

I actually do not see any reason for this to be a bad way to solve such kind of problems, though. The only question is: is there a way to understand the difference between a line that passes through a plane perpendicularly or not perpendicularly?

Comment: Your heading does not relate to your questions much. Yes, that is ok to decide if a line meets a plane. A line will be perpendicular to a plane if its direction (in your case (2, 1, -1)) is parallel to the normal to the plane (in your case (1, 1, -1)), so for your example line and plane are not perpendicular.

Comment: If all points of the line lie in the plane (1st case) then the line lie in the plane. If no points of the line lie in the plane (2nd case) then the line is parallel to the plane but does not lie in the plane (line which lies in the plane is parallel to the plane too that's why we need to add this remark), if the line has only one point which lies in the plane, then the line is crossing the plane. There is no difference in number of points between perpendicular and other crossing lines, that's why wee need other method to check if line is perpendicular. See my next comment.

Comment: The line $x=x_0+a_x t$, $y=y_0+a_y t$, $z=z_0+a_z t$ where $x_0$, $y_0$, $z_0$, $a_x$, $a_y$, $a_z$ are constants, will be perpendicular to plane $b_x x+b_y y+b_z z+c=0$, where $b_x$, $b_y$, $b_z$, $c$ are constants, if and only if vectors $(a_x,a_y,a_z)$ and $(b_x,b_y,b_z)$ are collinear, which is equivalent to the following simultaneous equations: $a_xb_y=a_yb_x$, $a_xb_z=a_zb_x$, $a_yb_z=a_zb_y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: Yes, you're correct.

In more detail:

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
Suppose your plane is given in Hesse normal form by
$\sigma=\{\vec{x}\in\R^3 \, \colon\, \vec{x}\cdot \vec{n} = d \}$ where $d$ is the distance to the origin and $n$ is the (outward-pointing) unit normal vector of $\sigma$. By "outward-pointing" I mean that $\vec{x}\cdot\vec{n} = d \geq 0$ for any point $\vec{x}\in \sigma$.
The line is given by
$L = \{\vec{x}\in\R^3 \, \colon\, \vec{x} = \vec{p} + t\vec{v}, t\in\R\}$
where $p$ is any point on $L$ and $v$ is the direction of $L$.

We want to find out if there is an intersection of $\sigma$ and $L$. So we plug the equation for the line into the equation for the plane, since any point in the intersection has to satisfy both equations and we thus get
$$
    \vec{p}\cdot \vec{n} + t (\vec{v}\cdot \vec{n}) = d.
$$
First, note that the vector $(\vec{p}\cdot \vec{n}) \vec{n}$ is the projection of the point $\vec{p}$ onto the line through the origin perpendicular to $\sigma$. So the number $\vec{p}\cdot \vec{n}$ gives you the (signed) distance of this projection to the origin.
Second, the number $\vec{v}\cdot \vec{n} = |\vec{v}| \cos\angle(\vec{v},\vec{n})$ tells you if plane and line are parallel (which includes the case of plane containing line) or transversal.

***Case 1***: $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{n}$ are *not* perpendicular, i.e. $\vec{v}\cdot \vec{n}\neq 0$. In other words, the plane and line are transversal (so there is an intersection point)
Then we find for the parameter
$$
    t = \tfrac{d - \vec{p}\cdot \vec{n}}{\vec{v}\cdot \vec{n}}
$$
and we also find the intersection point $\vec{z}$ by plugging this parameter back into the line equation
$$
    \vec{z} = \vec{p} + \tfrac{d - \vec{p}\cdot \vec{n}}{\vec{v}\cdot \vec{n}}\vec{v}.
$$

***Case 2***: $\vec{v}$ and $\vec{n}$ *are* perpendicular, i.e. $\vec{v}\cdot \vec{n}=0$. In other words, the plane and line are parallel and we need to decide if $L$ is contained in $\sigma$ or not.
Then the equation above reduces to $\vec{p}\cdot \vec{n} = d$.
If this equation holds that means any point $\vec{x}$ on the line fulfils the equation of the plane and thus $L$ is contained in $\sigma$.
Conversely, if this equation does *not* hold then no point $\vec{x}$ on the line lies in the plane and they are parallel with positive distance.
The distance is given by $|d-\vec{p}\cdot \vec{n}|$ if $\vec{p}\cdot \vec{n}\geq0$ or $d+\vec{p}\cdot \vec{n}$ if $\vec{p}\cdot \vec{n}<0$.

---

For your example, you may check this with:

$d=\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$,
$\vec{n} = \tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}} \begin{pmatrix}-1\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}$,
$\vec{p} = \begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and
$\vec{v} = \begin{pmatrix}2\\1\\-1\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you for this cool answer!

Comment: There was an error in the normal vector $\vec{n}$ and distance $d$ I wrote down for your example. I've fixed it now. It's only important to normalise $\vec{n}$ if you actually want to calculate the distance between line and plane, i.e. the last sentence I wrote above. Everything else works for non-unit normals $\vec{n}$ as well.